# Raw footage not appearing while using OpenCV in XCode

Tags: c++, opencv

Even though the icon appears on the dock, the camera window is not opening.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    VideoCapture cap(0);

    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Webcam is not open" << endl;
    }

    while (true){
        Mat image;
        Mat HSVimage;
        Mat processedImage;

        cap.read(image); //assigns matrices image to raw webcam footage
        imshow("test", image);

    }

}
```

[Screen Shot showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ2O9.png)

Comment: please use waitkey() after imshow()

Comment: @alex thanks for answering